# WKWebViewのレンダリングが体感として遅く感じる

Tags: ios, swift

現在、既存のWebViewを用いたアプリのUIWebViewをWKWebViewにリプレースする作業を現在進めています。このリプレースを行う中で、メモリ使用量及びCPU使用量に関しては圧倒的なパフォーマンス改善が見られたのですが、現在下記の様な問題に遭遇して対応に困っております。

**体感としてレンダリング速度が落ちているように感じる**

全体としてレンダリング速度もWKWebViewにしたことにより改善されているのですが、UIWebViewとWKWebViewを実機及びシュミレーターで操作して比べた所、下記の様な挙動の違いがありました。

**UIWebView:**
全ての要素のレンダリングが完了する前からViewにコンテンツが表示され、リソース(画像)は順次読み込みが完了する毎に表示されて行く。

**WKWebView:**
リソースを含めて全てのレンダリングが完了するまでは真っ白のViewが表示されており、全ての要素のレンダリングが完了した時点で一気にViewが表示される。

上記の挙動の違いのために、体感としてはUIWebViewの方がより早くレンダリングされているように感じてしまいます。もしも上記の様なレンダリング方法の違いがあるとすれば、WKWebViewあるいはWKWebViewConfigurationの値を変更することによりUIWebVIewと同じような挙動にすることは可能でしょうか？

もしくは上記以外の理由により、WKWebViewのレンダリングが遅く感じてしまう、あるいは実際に遅くなるという現象が起こり得るなら、改善策を教えて頂ければ幸いです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以前、UIWebViewとWKWebViewでベンチマークを取ってみました。
（ベンチマークにはOctane2.0とSunspiderを使いました。）

Octane2.0の結果
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2014/09/23/wkwebview2/

Sunspiderの結果
http://grandbig.github.io/blog/2014/10/02/wkwebview3/

(3Dレンダリングに関しては速いという結果が出ました。)

因みに、Googleマップの表示を試したときに、
WKWebViewの方がUIWebViewよりも体感として早く表示されたことが度々ありました。

何かの参考になれば幸いです。